# How to move Eclipse's auto insert semicolon to before the cursor?

Tags: java, eclipse

I used Intellij all throughout my time in college and I love it. However I am now a high school teacher and the current software being used is Eclipse. I may move to the community edition of Intellij, but for now I'm stuck with Eclipse.

I am having a problem when I type the following:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

When I type the opening parenthesis it auto adds the closing parenthesis. That is fine, and when I finish typing "System.in" I then type a closing parenthesis and the cursor moves past the one that was auto inserted, still fine, no problem yet.

However when I type the semicolon it places it after my cursor so that when I press enter to move onto my next line of code it takes the semicolon with it. I have tried turning on and off the selection to auto insert semicolons, that has no effect.

I need to know how to get it to position the semicolon before my cursor the same way every other typed character does. Or, less desired, a button to press that will get me past my cursor without moving my hands off the home row to the end button or using a mouse.

It is very basic things like this that got me using Intellij in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Check this and see if it is what you are looking for:

**Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing**

Mark the option *Automatically insert at correct position > Semicolons*

[image]

This will place the semicolon automatically at the end of the line, even if you are at the middle of it. It will work like an <kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: I have checked that, I have turned that feature on and off, and restarted the IDE after each change and it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: The problem is that after typing the semicolon, it gets placed at the end of the line, but my typing cursor is between the end parenthesis and the semicolon. So when I press enter to move to the next line to type my next line of code the semicolon moves to the next line as well because it is on the right side of the cursor.

I have found that it only happens, at least so far, with this particular line of code, I can continue another line of code after manually positioning my cursor, and it types out fine and places the semicolon in the proper position.